# How to write into a table without locking other transactions

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a central logging table, where various activities are logged. 
There is a procedure used for writing into the log, like this:

```
create procedure [client].[procClient_LogText]
(
    @LogText nvarchar(4000),
    @LogLevel tinyint = 1,
    @LogLongText nvarchar(max) = NULL,
    @LogModule nvarchar(200) = NULL
)
as
insert into dbo.tblLog(LogLevel, LogText, LogLongText, LogModule) 
values (@LogLevel, @LogText, @LogLongText, @LogModule);
```

Now I have one long transaction which takes 5-10 Minutes. During this, some steps are logged. The problem is that the log table is getting locked. And other processes get timeouts or are slowed down.

I want to write into the log table within a transaction just for protocolling, but the writing into the log itself should not necessarily be a part of the transaction. 
So in case of a rollback, the log should be still there.

Is that possible?

Comment: might be useful to see a high level view of what you are doing inside your transaction. as you might get different answers if it's one big task vs many smaller ones.

Answer (score 2):

If you call the `procedure` from your application server, then, instead of `insert` commands into the log `table` you can use `select` statements which you will be able to reuse after the transaction regardless of whether the transaction was committed or rolled back. Using these results you can generate an `insert` statement which will `insert` the records into the log `table`.

Comment: That's a really good proposal, +1, thanks for that! I will do some tries with that and comment it here later.

Comment: @askolotl, you are welcome, let me know about the result you get.

Comment: BTW greetings to Arad, I'm living Vienna, and I'm near Arad multiple times per year. vorbesc romaneste putin.

Comment: Danke schön! Then we can speak in Romanian as well, but my English is better. I am Hungarian though :)

Answer (score 1):

[Table variables aren't affected by user transaction rollback](http://sqlmag.com/t-sql/table-variable-tip).

So, at the beginning of your complex stored procedure create a table variable with the same structure as your permanent `tblLog` table.

Insert all logging steps into this table variable instead of the permanent `tblLog` table.

At the end of your complex stored procedure (regardless of committing or rolling back the main work) copy all rows from the table variable into the permanent `tblLog` table using one simple `INSERT`.

Thus locking of the permanent `tblLog` table will be kept to a minimum.

Obviously, there is a risk that some logs will be lost if the main stored procedure encounters some severe error, severe enough to abort the procedure in the middle and never reaching the final `INSERT` which copies rows from the temporary table variable into the permanent `tblLog` table.